# difference between chromedirver and phantomjs with python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I’m working to make web crawler with python by using selenium

Here, I successfully got contents by using chromedriver, but problem occurred when I tried to make 
Headless access crawling through PhantomJS. `find_element_by_id`, or `find_element_by_name` did not work
Is there any difference between these? Actually I am trying to make this as headless because I want to run this
Code in ubuntu server as a batch job without GUI support.

My script is like as below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
#driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/Users/user/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs')
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

#here I tried two different find_tag things but both didn’t work
user = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME,value="user:email")
password = driver.find_element_by_id('user_password')
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: please, add full traceback to the question, also can you provide us `url` as well?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "check.py", line 12, in <module>
    user = driver.find_element_by_name('user:email')
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 426, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element 'value': value})['value'] File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297,  `

Comment: It was not `url` specific problem. Whenever I tried changed url with changed tags, `username`, `user_email` etc. the problem emerged.

Comment: it says that there is no element with given name, so we (other users) can find out exact name (or search by other parameters like xpath) only with `url`

Comment: or you can provide minimal html content

Comment: you can test through gmail sign in page with `<input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Email or phone" name="identifier" id="identifierId" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">`   `find_by_id` with `idntifierId`

Comment: Can you share the `url` if it is public?